# power series for $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ around $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

i'm asked to find "some" of the first coefficients for the power series of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$.

what does $\sqrt w$ even mean for non real numbers?

assuming $\sqrt {z^2-1}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\log (z^2-1)}$, what branch of the $\log$ should I take?

and even if everything is well defined how can do this?

the usual technique so far has been to find $f$, $f'$, $f'',...$ in two differents ways: directly by the function and by the power series. Then I evaluate at $z=0$ using the function directly to get the coefficients, but that's way to complicated in this case.

how can I solve this?

Comment: Can you find the power series expansion (or at least the start of it) of $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ around $0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer what definition should I take for $\sqrt{1-z^2}$? is it $e^{\frac{1}{2}\log (z^2-1)}$? if it is, I don't think I can. is the power series for $\log (1-z)$ useful here?

Comment: On a small disk around $0$, $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ is one of the two continuous functions that satisfy $f(z)^2 = 1-z^2$ (one of the two has $f(0) = 1$, the other $f(0) = -1$). By general nonsense, such a continuous function must necessarily be holomorphic. You can use $\exp (\frac12\log (1-z^2))$, which at least makes the holomorphy obvious. But you could better a binomial series.

Comment: Branch cut along $\displaystyle\left[-1,1\right]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it should be silly for finding the power series of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ by first finding the general form of $\dfrac{d^n}{dz^n}\sqrt{z^2-1}$ as the latter is extremely complicated, and having the following approach:

$\sqrt{z^2-1}=i\sqrt{1-z^2}=i\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!(z^2)^n}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}=i\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!z^{2n}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$f(z)=\sqrt{z^2-1}$

$f'(z)=\cfrac{z}{\sqrt{z^2-1}}=\cfrac{z}{f(z)}$

> Now suppose you have $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_nz^n+o(z^n)$, and plug it into the equality above to find $f'(z)=b_0+b_1z+\dots+b_nz^n+o(z^n)$ and the integrate to find $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_{n+1}z^{n+1}+o(z^{n+1})$

Comment: I'm not sure how to differentiate $\sqrt {z^2-1}$ because I don't know what $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is

Comment: I can't help you with that, I have never done any complex analysis. But if you are asked the first terms of the power series, I'm pretty sure this is what is expected.

Comment: yes I think so too, but I still need to know what i'm doing. i would upvote though, unfortunately i cant